# How to display data in a visualforce page from a salesforce object; but when there is no data, create it?

Tags: apex, visualforce

When the page loads, it should retrieve data from a custom object. I know I can do that with apex:outputtext; but I need to check, if there is no data then the user has to create it, and in that case I know I should use apex:inputfield.
How can I display inputfield or outputtext acording to the condition if there is data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your Visualforce page to include both, and then only render one of them by making use of the `rendered` attribute.

e.g.

```html
<apex:pageSection rendered="{!MyRecord.Id == null}">
    <apex:inputField value="{!MyRecord.Name}"/>
</apex:pageSection>
<apex:pageSection rendered="{!MyRecord.Id != null}">
    <apex:outputField value="{!MyRecord.Name}"/>
</apex:pageSection>
```

Page performance will become excruciatingly slow if you specify enough `rendered` attributes (which can be easy to do if you use it in an `<apex:repeat>`, `<apex:pageBlockTable>`, or `<apex:dataTable>`), so I believe it's better practice to keep the rendering decisions as few (and on as high-level components) as practical.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I only need this for 4 parameters so I think it'll be fine with  performance